# How to toggle Icon in Html

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am making a to-do list App using node js so what i want to do is I want to check my task when its done in the app. But the issue persist that i am not being able to check . As I am toggling icons here from like a circle to checked circle. please tell how to do.

```
let tick= document.getElementById("hola");


tick.onclick=function(){

   if(tick.classList.contains("fa-circle"))
   {
    tick.classList.replace("fa-circle","fa-circle-check");
   }
   else{
    
    tick.classList.replace("fa-circle-check","fa-circle");
   }
}
```

```
  <% for (let i of work_list) { %>
      <li class="task-list-item" id="edit-func">
        <p id="id_list"><%= i.list %></p>
        <p ><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i><span id="id_date"><%=i.date %></span></p>
        <p id="id_category"><%= i.category %></p>
        <a href="/delete-task/?id=<%= i._id %>" ><i class="fa-solid fa-trash delete-icon"></i></a>
        <a href="" id="edit-func"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen edit"></i></a>
        <h1 class="done-task" ><i class="fa-regular fa-circle" id="hola" name="task-hola"></i></h1>
      </li>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: You code works, but problem is most likely that you have multiple elements with the same id. ID must be unique

Comment: I am using unique ID only

Comment: Unless work_list only contain 1 element then you are getting multiple elements with the same id, in `for (let i of work_list)`. Also make sure your javascript is running after your html is rendered

Comment: can you write the code? I am still not getting you

Comment: What error message are you getting (probably in the console)?

Comment: can you please resolve it

Comment: I am not getting any error message its just i am not being able to toggle the check circle icon onwebsite

Comment: I can spot **id="edit-func"** at least twice in your html, and like mentioned if ```work_list``` contains more than 1 item, more duplicate ids will appear. That doesn't have to be your specific problem though as the code doesn't contain any crictical errors. (I believe it should work on the first item in the list). What do you see in the console if you add ```console.log(tick);``` directly below your first line of code?

Comment: I am getting my icon tag

Answer (score 0):

You should probably clean up your markup regarding the duplicate ids. But changing an Icon on interaction for a list of of items can be done like this:

```js
const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-list-item');

console.log(tasks.length);
//If you see nothing: your Javascript is probably not loading
//If you see 0, your script is running before the HTML is rendered on the page

tasks.forEach(task => {
  const taskIcon = task.querySelector('.done-task .fa-regular');

  task.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('click!');
    //If you do not see 'click!' in the console, your click event isn't being triggered;

    if(taskIcon.contains('fa-circle') {
      taskIcon.replace('fa-circle', 'fa-circle-check');
    } else {
      taskIcon.replace('fa-circle-check', 'fa-circle');
    }
  });
);
```

If the console is logging all the messages, but you still don't see the icon change, it is also possible that your FontAwesome isn't loading properly.